# How to register a COM-visible assembly in HKCU (without MSI)

Tags: com, regasm

It appears that regasm.exe is only capable of registering a COM-visible assembly in HKLM, for the whole system.  Is there a way to do it for the logged-in user only, without an MSI installer?

I've considered using regasm to dump a .reg file, and then processing that to add the registry entries myself... don't want to reinvent the wheel if I can avoid it.

Comment: Sure, that would work.  Using a reg-free COM manifest is the better mousetrap.  Use the `<clrClass>` element.

Comment: The assembly I'm trying to register is an Outlook AddIn so I don't think that's an option, Outlook has to be able to look it up when it starts.  Dumping/parsing the .reg file seems to work so far.